# Java mystery path in Windows 7 prompt

Tags: java

I recently noticed that my PATH setting in Windows had incorrect pointers to older versions of Java. What is odd is that the java -version command still works at the command prompt and it gives the version of Java that does correspond to the latest JRE I have installed. This is also the version represented in Control Panel and it is the VM version referenced by Eclipse. What I'm confused about is how does the command prompt know where to find the java executables if the path is set incorrectly?

Comment: Type `where java` and see which java is run.

Comment: Well, what is PATH set to, and what do you expect it to be set to?  (Post the whole PATH verbatim in your question.)

Comment: did you check `JAVA_HOME` or other env setting? (latest version could also be referenced in some sort of registry?)

Comment: Check if your system variables and User variables point to different java versions. You might be executing the command in context of your user id. The user variables take preference over system variables.

Comment: I can't be sure since you didn't post the actual file path or the PATH variable to see what they are, but several programs keep the file path the same, while merely updating the files contained within, for simplicity.

In my experience, I didn't think that Java did this.

Comment: Path to java binaries should be the first in `%PATH%` variable. Also, in linux there is a `update-alternatives` command, but I don't know if there is a command in cmd like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no mystery. There are going to be at least two versions of Java installed on your computer: The one you installed manually, and the one Windows uses (most likely inside the \system32 folder).

when you type the *java* command at the command prompt, the operating system (windows) resolves this command by: 1) executing the command located on the current directory, 2) finding the command in one of the paths declared in the PATH.

I have multiple Java versions installed on my computer. The one I want to use to develop software is the one I made sure is declared **first** on my PATH variable.

Comment: The key phrase is "first" in the PATH variable.

Comment: Actually, I fooled myself here. The first item on the path was C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath. This directory was installed by Oracle (wild guess) and was moved in front. In addition, it only contains the 3 main java executables. So even though all my Java paths that I set were out of date this one happened to have the up to date executables with the same version coincidentally matching my installed JRE. Oracle should probably not do that but I guess they have to ensure the presence of Java for there SQL Developer tool.

Comment: @TWiStErRob your comparison doesn't make sense because it is not the same thing. IE is a Windows built-in product which "requires" Java to support certain webpages. You can configure this through "Internet Options" menu. Anyway, your comment is not accurate.